# SSH access from outside to a pc inside network

Tags: networking, ssh, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSH access from outside to a pc inside network](https://serverfault.com/questions/113632/ssh-access-from-outside-to-a-pc-inside-network)

I have a static IP and ADSL router linked to a linksys wireless router to which all my machines are connected.

I would want to setup SVN on one of machines and provide SSH access which should be accessible by users outside my network.

Would this be possible? Even just SVN access through web should be fine. Please let me know what all things should be done to achieve this ? I have Ubuntu VM running in a iMac Leopard machine and another 2 Win 7 32/64 bit machines. I can setup standalone Ubuntu or Win XP on another machine.

Thanks,
Raja.

Comment: These are usually in your router settings, forward requests to the SSH port to the machine you wish to SSH to.  I wouldn't be surprised if this question gets moved to serverfault or perhaps superuser though.

Answer (score 2):

You can [forward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) tcp port 22 (the port SSH uses) to the machine you setup the SVN server on. This will allow outside access to that machine for SSH using your static IP address.